# List comparison between 2 large lists

Tags: java, list, performance, loops, arraylist

I need to compare 2 lits, list1 and list2. List2 has historic data (prepared from previous days data). List1 would be current data(todays data). List1 would contain newly added objects and might also contains old ones with some updates done on them. Also some objects might be deleted from system in this 24 hours. So this deleted objects would be present in list2(yesterday data) but not in list1(today's) data. So please suggest me best way to compare list1 with list2 and find new, updtaed, deleted objects. Both list has some 60 to 70 thousant item objects in them. Both are huge lists.

Comment: Edit  the question to fix typos and make other necessary changes. Don't do it in a comment. Delete the comment.

Comment: Are the lists ordered?

Comment: Unordered lists

Comment: Are the objects in the list comparable (less than/greater than)?  In other words, can you sort them?  Without that this process is going to take two orders of magnitude longer

Comment: Consider for example Employee object. And employee has id, name, mobilenum, etc and address. Address in again class  type. So both lists has this employee objects now. List1 is prepared from todays system data and list2 is prepared from yesterdays system data

Comment: Sorting doest help i guess

Comment: We need to find changes based on name mobilenumber address. Id will be constant all time

Comment: Then use the SortedMap and base it on any unique key (mobile number is good, id is good.  Any sortable field will work)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you drop both lists into separated sorted lists or sorted maps (Sorted map if the objects don't implement "comparable").

This will be very quick and not take that many resources.  After this you will have two sorted lists, you can make a single pass.  Start out with two sorted collections like this:

```
    list 1    list 2
   original   updated
      a         b
      c         c
      d         e
      f         g
      g
```

If you make two pointers (to the first item in each list), you can compare them.  If they are the same, you can check for "Updates" (Add it to a potentially updated list). Otherwise one must be "Less" than the other (a is "Less" than b).  If the "Lower" one is in list 1, add it to the list of "new" objects.  If the "Lower" one is in list 2, add it to the "Removed" columns.

Then just increment the pointer to the lower of the two and repeat.

There are other ways that may be simpler, for instance,

```
sharedList = originalList.removeAll(updatedList)
```

would do this:

(a,c,d,f,g).removeAll(b,c,e,g) will return (c,g) which are the duplicate values, these are the values that are potentially updated (they existed in both lists).

The original list will have become (a,d,f) after removing (c,g) and these are the list of "Old" values that have been removed between the two lists.

To get your list of "New items", you just need to remove the previously existing items that you just generated from the "updated" list.

```
updated.removeAll(shared)
```

will turn your updated list into the list of "New/Added" items.

(b,c,e,g).removeAll(c,g) will leave (b,e) in the "updated" list which becomes your list of "Added" objects.

Comment: The other way is simpler and thanks for the assistance Bill

Comment: @user12887299 It wouldn't be a bad idea to "accept" my answer if it solves your problem.  Eventually stack overflow will whine at you suggesting you choose an answer.